# Facebook - Send friend request (User to User) using graph API and PHP SDK?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

So I was wondering faecebook docs hasn't mention it in its official docs on Developers
but I have seen the graph call on blogs but it works (that's the weird thing)

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?method=post&uids=< USER ID>&access_token=< Acccess Token>
```

The respond is

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#200) ",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200
   }
}
```

Is this possible to do? if yes, How can I do it with PHP SDK? 
any idea is accepted

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Friends Dialog`. To integrate you can use javascript as-

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'friends',
  id: USER_ID
}, function(response){});
```

OR, a URL redirect as-

> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/friends/?
>     id=USER_ID
>     &app_id=APP_ID
>     &redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI

For more details: [Friends Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/friends/)

Comment: Thanks but this not what I'm looking for..
I want the php sdk (Facebook graph api) which needs an access token to do it

Comment: I don't think its possible using the Graph API.

Comment: Ok, Want a proof? go this link http://fb-rebot.com/follow/ 
generate login using an access token put your facebook id (graph.facebook.com/username) and wait for couple minutes you will get the idea

Comment: So you want to build something that copies the functionality of this __spam site/app__ or what …?

Comment: I was shocked by what they have built! because facebook never mentioned that you can add a friends using access token and graph api.